# Could you explain the meaning of the sentence

Tags: general-topology

[image: The $X$ set explanation][image: The sentence itself]

My native language is not English and can't realize what does the first sentence on the picture sentence mean. In particular, "each angle and the $x$ axis are components". Could you explain it in other words?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier for us to know what is going on if you could tell us what $X$ is.

Comment: I thought there is enough information, because just explanation of "are components" is needed

Comment: Added the explanation

Comment: Part 3 is very poorly said, even for English, which is a language where very bad phrasing can often be easily understood.   If you are already experienced with  the topic then you can infer what he $should$ have said.  But if not,....

Comment: I disagree with the "down-vote"  so I gave you a +1. I think it is fair to ask for an explanation of a brief passage in a textbook, whether or not the passage is written well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are talking about *connected* components here. The set $X$ consists of the $x$-axis, along with infinitely many "angles". An angle in this case means one horizontal ray, meeting a line segment from $(0,1)$ at an angle. Here is a hastily-drawn picture of one such "angle":

[image]

As you can see from the drawing in your book, $X$ consists of infinitely many such angles, all joined together at $(0,1)$.

If you remove $(0,1)$ from this space, then each of those angles will be connected omponents of the space that is left.

Comment: I do know what angle means, but I don't get what does "... will be connected components of the space that is left" mean

Comment: @ЕгорПономарёв When you remove the point $(0,1)$ from $X$ to make $X-\{(0,1)\}$, then what we get is a large collection of angles, and the $x$-axis. These are all components of the space $X-\{(0,1)\}$. They weren't components of the space $X$, since in $X$ they were connected at $(0,1)$. They are components of $X-\{(0,1)\}$ because now we've removed the point where they were connected.